# Prove this is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I started the following question, but stopped after a few steps, I wonder if the problem contains enough information.

If $ G $ is  a set and $ * $ is a binary operation on $ G $, show $ (G,*) $ is a group if

(1) $ * $ is associative

(2) $ * $ is commutative

(3) $\forall a,b\in G $, $ \exists c\in G $ such that $ a*c=b $.

Attempt:
$ * $ is associative by assumption, thus it remains to show the existence of identity and inverses.
Identity: let $a\in G$, take $ b=a $,  by (3),
$ \exists c\in G :ac=a.$ Let $ a'\in G $, be an element differ from $ a $, by (3) again $\exists c':a'c'=a'$, it remains to show that $ c=c'. $  (Wonder if there is enough information)

Comment: I think there is enough, keep going. I wonder what happens if you let $c$ be the right hand side, and $a$ where it is in equality (3)... Out of interest, where did you find this problem?

Comment: @mdave feeling bad of saying this, it is in a friend's (lets just say) "homework"

Comment: Yo don't need to show uniqueness of identity element and inverse elements, just to show they exist (both left or both right).

Comment: @Gilberto López I wasn't trying to show uniqueness,  I  need to find a c that works on all element as an identity, i.e. "there exist c, for all a",  while (3) only guarantees "for all a, there exist c"

Comment: since this is someone's "homework", I change the body of the problem to a picture so that it is not searchable before the due day.

Comment: @Wei Yang, For future use, can you change it back? Or at least change the wording. For some devices, photos do not show up that great...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't stated that $G$ is nonempty, this is essential. However, under this assumption, we can prove that $(G,\cdot)$ is a group.

Let $g\in G$. Then by hypothesis (3), there exists $e\in G$ such that $g\cdot e = g$. Let $h\in G$ be arbitrary. Then there exists $c\in G$ such that $g\cdot c = h$ (by hypothesis (3) again), so that
\begin{align*}
h\cdot e &= (g\cdot c)\cdot e\\
&= g\cdot (c\cdot e)\\
&= g\cdot (e\cdot c)\\
&= (g\cdot e)\cdot c\\
&= g\cdot c\\
&= h.
\end{align*}

Thus, $e$ is an identity element for all of $G$. Right inverses exist for all elements of $G$ by (3), and the fact that $e$ is both a left and right identitie and that the inverses described are both left and right inverses follow from commutativity of $\cdot$.